# Android / Getting with application name of any status bar notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-statusbar, notification-listener

In `NotificationListenerService` class, there are `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` and `onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)` functions.

Consider the `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` function.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = new String();
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
}
```

So, with this function, I am able to get title, text, app icon and package name of any new notifications whatever that come in the mobile device from my own Android application, of course. I want to get the app name of the notification (for example, if the package name is `com.kpbird.nlsexample`, the app name is `NLService`, so the app name can be significantly different enough from the portion of package name to the right of the rightmost dot in the package name). How can I be able to do that process of extracting the app name from the posted status bar notification of the mobile device for the new notifications as they come in, forever?

```
for(String key : extras.keySet())
        {
            Log.i("Key", key);
        }
```

> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.title
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.subText
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.showChronometer
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.icon
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.text
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.progress
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.progressMax
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.appInfo
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.showWhen
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.largeIcon
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.infoText
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.originatingUserId
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.progressIndeterminate
>
> 2018-12-07 11:49:56.543 26392-26392/android.notificationlistener I/Key: android.remoteInputHistory

It appears that there is no key available in `Bundle extras` for getting the app name. There also seems to be no variable declared in `StatusBarNotification sbn` class available for getting the app name. However, it seems that it is possible to get the timestamp that is essentially the time at which any notification had been posted into the status bar of the mobile device from the `StatusBarNotification sbn` class for the new notifications as they come in.

`StatusBarNotifications.java`

> private final String pkg;
>
> private final int id;
>
> private final String tag;
>
> private final String key;
>
> private String groupKey;
>
> private String overrideGroupKey;
>
> private final int uid;
>
> private final String opPkg;
>
> private final int initialPid;
>
> private final Notification notification;
>
> private final UserHandle user;
>
> private final long postTime;

Comment: So you have the package name and just want to extract the app name from it?

Comment: Yes, I have already observed that it is possible for me to get app name from package name by using `final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();` `ApplicationInfo ai;` `try {` `ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( pack, 0);` `} catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {` `ai = null;` `}` `final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");` or from app id (I am not sure about it another type of thing though).

Comment: My own question is that whether it is possible for me or not to get app name quite directly enough only from keys available in `Bundle extras` or from their own available variables declared in `StatusBarNotification sbn` class quite directly enough only. I have already observed that another type of thing, I have actually.